# Mousewheel scroll to anchor

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the mousewheel scroll to scroll to anchors on the page. I'm using this piece of code I found on a different thread here but it's not working. Am I missing something?

```
(function() {
var delay = false;

jQuery(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if(delay) return;

delay = true;
setTimeout(function(){delay = false},200)

var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

var a= document.getElementsByClass ('anchor');
if(wd < 0) {
  for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
    var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
    if(t >= 40) break;
  }
}
else {
  for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
    if(t < -20) break;
  }
}

if(i >= 0 && i < a.length) {
  jQuery('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
  });
}  
});     
})();
console.clear();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code i found `var a= document.getElementsByClass('anchor');` there is no such type of function , it should be as `var a= document.getElementsByClassName('anchor');`

```js
(function() {
var delay = false;

jQuery(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if(delay) return;

delay = true;
setTimeout(function(){delay = false},200)

var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

var a= document.getElementsByClassName('anchor');
if(wd < 0) {
  for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
    var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
    if(t >= 40) break;
  }
}
else {
  for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
    if(t < -20) break;
  }
}

if(i >= 0 && i < a.length) {
  jQuery('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
  });
}  
});     
})();
console.clear();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/><br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<a class="anchor">ganesh</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not clear console if you trying to debug something, coz it will also clear all errors in console. If you will remove last string of code you will see that you have error
`document.getElementsByClass is not a function`.
So you need to use getElementsByClassName.

You just need to change
`var a= document.getElementsByClass ('anchor');`
to
`var a = document.getElementsByClassName('anchor');`